# Is it possible to turn off multiple addresses in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

The title says it all, is it possible to turn off multiple addresses? Now I can add a different send address and an invoice address, this option breaks a payment option I have since it requires all addresses to be the same.

So my question, is it possible to turn that off? Have the customer only be able to pick 1 address for everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, it is not possible in Magento but you can do this programmatically.

To do this, you need to create a custom module. Below are the steps:

> Create file app/etc/Stack_Removeshipping.xml and put below code:

```
<modules>
<Stack_Removeshipping>
<version>0.0.1</version>
</Stack_Removeshipping>
</modules>
```

> Rewrite block class Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage to change the function to get checkout steps codes.

```
<global>
<blocks>
<stack_removeshipping>
<class>Stack_Removeshipping_Block</class>
</stack_removeshipping>
<checkout>
<rewrite>
<onepage>Stack_Removeshipping_Block_Checkout_Onepage</onepage>
</rewrite>
</checkout>
</blocks>
</global>
```

> create a file Onepage.php inside folder app/code/local/Stack/Removeshipping/Blocks/Checkout/

```
class Stack_Removeshipping_Block_Checkout_Onepage extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage
{
protected function _getStepCodes()
{
return array('login', 'billing', 'shipping_method', 'payment', 'review');
}
}
```

> Remove the checkbox and make “use_for_shipping” always true. For this, we need to change the billing.phtml

```
<frontend>
<layout>
<updates>
<stack_removeshipping>
<file>stack/checkout.xml</file>
</stack_removeshipping>
</updates>
</layout>
</frontend>
```

> Add new layout xml file into your theme

app/design/frontend/[themepackage]/[theme]/layout/[yourlayoutfile].xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<checkout_onepage_index>
<reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>stack/checkout/billing.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

> Copy billing.phtml from app/design/frontend/base/default/checkout/onepage folder into app/design/frontend/[themepackage]/[theme]/template/stack/checkout folder and find following code:

```
<li class="control">
<input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_yes" value="1"<?php if ($this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Ship to this address')) ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = true;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_yes"><?php echo  $this->__('Ship to this address') ?></label></li>
<li class="control">
<input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_no" value="0"<?php if (!$this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Ship to different address')) ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_no"><?php echo $this->__('Ship to different address') ?></label>
</li>
```

> Replace it with:

```
<li class="control">
<input type="hidden" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_yes" value="1"  />
</li>
```

> Remove shipping address section from right sidebar progress. For this edit the layout xml stack/checkout.xml and your new xml will look like this:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<checkout_onepage_index>
<reference name="checkout.onepage.billing">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>stack/checkout/billing.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
<reference name="checkout.progress">
<remove name="shipping.progress"></remove>
</reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

> Rewrite the OnepageController.php. For this first edit add following code inside in config.xml file:

```
<routers>
<checkout>
<args>
<modules>
<stack_removeshipping before="Mage_Checkout">Stack_Removeshipping</stack_removeshipping>
</modules>
</args>
</checkout>
</routers>
```

> Copy **OnepageController.php** from **app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers** folder inside **app/code/local/Stack/Removeshipping/controllers** folder and except **saveBillingAction** function delete all other function. Add we just have to comment.

After changes, controller file should look like this:

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', "Mage_Checkout") . DS . "OnepageController.php";
class Stack_Removeshipping_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
/**
* Save checkout billing address
*/
public function saveBillingAction()
{
if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
return;
}
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
$data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
$customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);
if (isset($data['email'])) {
$data['email'] = trim($data['email']);
}
$result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);
if (!isset($result['error'])) {
if ($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
$result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
$result['update_section'] = array(
'name' => 'payment-method',
'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
);
} elseif (isset($data['use_for_shipping']) && $data['use_for_shipping'] == 1) {
$result['goto_section'] = 'shipping_method';
$result['update_section'] = array(
'name' => 'shipping-method',
'html' => $this->_getShippingMethodsHtml()
);
/* $result['allow_sections'] = array('shipping');
$result['duplicateBillingInfo'] = 'true';*/
} else {
$result['goto_section'] = 'shipping';
}
}
$this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}
}
}
```